# setup Antlr CLASSPATH in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath, antlr

I am trying to setup Antlr4 in Ubuntu.
I've tried adding the antlr4 jar to (.cshrc) file with the command:

```
set CLASSPATH = ($CLASSPATH /user/Documents/Antlr4/bin/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar)
```

when trying to source my (.cshrc) file i am getting the error:

```
CLASSPATH: Undefined variable
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do it like so -

```
#!/usr/bin/csh

if $?CLASSPATH then
  setenv CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/user/Documents/Antlr4/bin/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar
else
  setenv CLASSPATH /user/Documents/Antlr4/bin/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar
endif
echo $CLASSPATH
```

And you might test it like so,

```
$ CLASSPATH=A ./test.csh
A:/user/Documents/Antlr4/bin/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar
$ ./test.csh
/user/Documents/Antlr4/bin/antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar
```

Comment: i just can't thank you enough, I've been struggling with this, and now it is finally working. 
However when i had the if statement i got an error which is setenv too many arguments, i used only the option in the else-statement, and now it is working